# Familiar Sheet Music Identification!

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I'm trying to identify this music. I believe it's from a game, Its very familiar... but I just can't put my finger on what it is. Hoping someone here might be able to figure it out!

Notes I cobbled together to play the tune as best I can...
http://onlinesequencer.net/380991

[image: The Sheet I have]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, could it be [Beethoven's "Moonlight Sonata"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsOUcikyGRk) ?  ( Piano Sonata No. 14 in C-sharp minor "Quasi una fantasia", Op. 27, No. 2), particularly the bits around 2:39

Comment: I'd looked at Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata several times, just not this 'version'(?). Well found!

Comment: @Rorrik, I'm glad that users from this community did helped you. For future questions, here you can learn [how you can improve your question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/368/1721) 
and increase your chances for find the music you're looking for.